# Can I pass JWT decoded data in express.js req object?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am trying to find a solution where I can have a middleware check on a route that verifies the JWT. Since this verification decodes it as well as verifying, I would like to pass the decoded data along to the route without having to decode again. See my current solution below:

```
  //route.js
  app.get("/donations", helpers.protected, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user)
  });





  //helper.js
module.exports.protected = (req, res, next) => {
    const jwt_token = req.cookies["auth"];

  jwt.verify(jwt_token, nconf.get("jwt:secret"), (err, decoded) => {
    if (err || !decoded) {
      logErr(error.INVALID_JWT, err, req);
      return res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      req.user = decoded;
      return next();
    }
 });
};
```

The goal is to keep code simple and clean in the routes by putting validation logic in a middle function. I want to be able to prevent having to decode twice but also be secure. Can I use req.user = decoded; as I have shown above? Can req.user ever be modified or placed in a HTTP request from the client? Would using res.locals.user = decoded; be any better or worse to use?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using Passport? There's a [jwt strategy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) you could use.

Comment: Yeah, I have used passport in the past, I am actually not a big fan of it. For me, libraries that do too much of the work make it hard to customize and debug. Similar to using Rails in ruby, it's a great framework but when you need to have some custom use case or work flow, it becomes difficult to do what you want because it's so opinionated

Comment: I'd probably say Passport has all the available hooks that for a typical auth scenario you'd need....but over and above that, JS is pretty flexible in general, so there's usually never a problem extending libraries or frameworks to suit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you pass the `decoded` into `req`

**BUT**

I would avoid setting decoded to `req.user`, simply because `req.user` is related to session user. Just use `req.decoded` or something else. You only need to use `res.locals` when you need to set the object globally to the rendering engine that you are using.